# Fieldset collapsed by default

Tags: 7, forms

I'm working on a Drupal 7 project where I use the form API to build a form. I want my form's fieldsets to be collapsed by default.

I use the following code:

```
$form['fieldset'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('categories group'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
);
```

When refreshing the page the fieldset is not collapsed although it has the *collapsed* class. When clicking on the fieldset for the first time, the  class is removed, while clicking for the second time the class is added and the fieldset is collapsed.

How do I force a fieldset to be collapsed by default?

Comment: According to the docs this should work unless you have interference from a module or custom theme overriding the behavior.

Comment: Using `'#collapsed' => TRUE` is what Drupal core does. If you have any issue, that most probably depends from the used theme, or there is JavaScript code that uncollapse the fieldset.